TS 2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' even with declaration
While developing the JWT token system for my API, I ran into a weird problem. Basically, it is giving me the error
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:60:17 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.  

60             req.user = user;
                   ~~~~

    at createTSError (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1617:30)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1689:10
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\mydirectory\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2339 ]

even though I properly defined the Request in types\express\index.d.ts. I also tried "moduleResolution": "node10" and "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "types/**/*.d.ts"] in my tsconfig.json. I have searched the internet and even asked AI for some help, but to no avail.
For reference, I'm making an Express API with Prisma DB as the database, and the error is in authenticateJWT.
Code
index.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import * as queries from './queries';
import { createHash, randomBytes } from 'crypto';
import jwt, { Jwt, JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { body, validationResult } from 'express-validator';
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const app = express();
const port: number = 8000;
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const loginLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 5,
    message: 'Too many login attempts, please try again after 15 minutes',
    standardHeaders: true,
    legacyHeaders: false,
})
const createUserLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    max: 5, // Limit each IP to 5 create account requests per hour
    message: 'Too many accounts created from this IP, please try again after 1 hour',
    standardHeaders: true,
    legacyHeaders: false,
})

app.use(express.json())

function isJwtPayload(decoded: any): decoded is JwtPayload {
    return typeof decoded !== 'string' && typeof decoded === 'object' && decoded !== null && 'userId' in decoded && 'username' in decoded;
}

// Middleware for JWT authentication
const authenticateJWT = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  
    if (authHeader) {
      const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1]; // Bearer <token>

      if (!jwtSecret) {
        throw new Error('JWT secret is not defined');
      }
  
      jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Token expired' });
            } else if (err.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid token' });
            } else {
                console.error("JWT Verification Error:", err);
                return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Failed to authenticate token' });
            }
        }
        
        if (isJwtPayload(user)) {
            req.user = user; // <--- here is the error
            next();
        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401); // No token provided
    }
};
  
app.post('/login', loginLimiter, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {username, password} = req.body;
        const user = await queries.getUserByUsername(username);
        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json({error: "User not found"})
        }

        const passwordHashed = createHash('sha256').update(password).digest('hex');
        const passwordMatch = await queries.verifyPasswordHash(username, passwordHashed);
        if (passwordMatch) {
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({userId: user?.id, username: user?.username}, jwtSecret as string, {expiresIn: '15m'});
            const refreshToken = randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
            if (typeof user?.id !== 'number') {
                throw new Error('User ID is not a number');
            }
            await queries.updateRefreshToken(user?.id, refreshToken);
            res.json({ accessToken, refreshToken });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({error: "Invalid credentials"});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error logging in: ", err);
        res.status(500).json({error: "Failed to login"})
    } finally {
        queries.disconnect();
    }
})

app.post('/refresh', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;

    if (!refreshToken) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Refresh token required' });
    }

    try {
        const user = await queries.findUserByRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        if (!user) {
            res.status(403).json({ error: 'Invalid refresh token' });
        }

        jwt.verify(refreshToken, jwtSecret as string, async (err: any, decoded: any) => {
            if (err) {
                if (typeof user?.id !== 'number') {
                    throw new Error('User ID is not a number');
                }
                await queries.updateRefreshToken(user?.id, null)
                res.status(403).json({ error: 'Invalid refresh token' });
            }
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user?.id, username: user?.username }, jwtSecret as string, { expiresIn: '15m' });
            res.json({ accessToken });
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error refreshing token:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to refresh token' });
    } finally {queries.disconnect()}
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`));

types\express\index.d.ts
import express from 'express';
import { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import 'express-serve-static-core'

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: JwtPayload;
        }
    }
}

tsconfig.json (I removed much of the commented code from the generated code from adding ts)
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "node10",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "types/**/*.d.ts"] 
}

Dependencies in package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^6.0.1",
    "@prisma/extension-accelerate": "^1.2.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7",
    "express": "^4.21.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.5.0",
    "express-validator": "^7.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.9",
    "prisma": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }


What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?
If you need anymore information, feel free to comment and I will edit this post with the needed information.
Thank you for your time.

This question is similar to: Extend Express Request object using Typescript. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I found the answer to my question by adding "files":["types/express/index.d.ts"] in my tsconfig.json file. What should I do with this question? Should I delete it?
